# How to determine font width in pixels in Swing application for remote desktop

Tags: java, swing, fonts, font-size, rdp

I have created a swing application and I invoked it remotely via putty.
In the actual system the font size is coming proper with the below code but at remote console I am not getting the size of the font.

I am using the below code to find the font size in pixels for the current environment:

```
FontMetrics metrics = control
                    .getFontMetrics(control.getFont());
int hgt = metrics.getHeight();
int adv = metrics.stringWidth();
```

but the above code is not working when invoked remotely from putty.

I used the approach from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html

Do anyone know how to handle it.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: What result do you get?

Answer (score 0):

`.stringWidth` is missing a `String` parameter. The method takes that `String` and measures it with the given `Font`, resulting in the given text's *advance width*. You should re-read that documentation you linked.